# Elasticsearch Test Container time out

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, testcontainers

I am pulling ES 7.15.2 for writing tests from within java application

```
    private static final DockerImageName ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE =
          DockerImageName
                .parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch")
                .withTag("7.15.2");
```

The docker starts up fine. Logs

```
astha.gupta@P-TQ-MAC-AGUP Quinn % docker logs 61fe3dcd2dba -f
2022/01/12 23:17:11 Pinging Docker...
2022/01/12 23:17:11 Docker daemon is available!
2022/01/12 23:17:11 Starting on port 8080...
2022/01/12 23:17:11 Started!
2022/01/12 23:17:11 New client connected: 172.17.0.1:56948
2022/01/12 23:17:11 Received the first connection
2022/01/12 23:17:11 Adding {"label":{"org.testcontainers.sessionId=8d6280af-d612-4186-90e2-29aae1c4101f":true,"org.testcontainers=true":true}}
```

But seems like the application hangs and then errors out

```
22/01/12 15:20:03 INFO  [docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2]: Container docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2 is starting: f7fe3708ec5fac3d557685fd650e172ce9146f4ea3159e586bde0ff30acb0238
22/01/12 15:20:03 INFO org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HttpWaitStrategy: /elated_lewin: Waiting for 120 seconds for URL: http://localhost:58934/ (where port 58934 maps to container port 9200)
22/01/12 15:22:03 ERROR  [docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2]: Could not start container
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for URL to be accessible (http://localhost:58934/ should return HTTP 200)
```

Any clue what could be happening?

EDIT:
The test https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/d0c4ced72ddca93838c1107b66913b5141872906/modules/elasticsearch/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchContainerTest.java#L88 with the wait works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Elasticsearch](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/elasticsearch/) container instead of a generic docker one

Comment: I am using the recommended image https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Comment: I believe `ElasticsearchContainer` is using official images too

Comment: Just using `ElasticsearchContainer()` is deprecated.

Comment: If I understand [the code](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchContainer.java) correctly, only some parameters are deprecated but not the class itself.